# How to search or find data in google spreedsheets using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-api, google-sheets-api

I want to search some data in google spreadsheet's column A using C#

Am able to get the values present or not using this below code:

```
var range = $"{sheet}!A1:F5";
        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request =
                service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(SpreadsheetId, range);

        var response = request.Execute();
        IList<IList<object>> values = response.Values;

        if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Found !!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Found !!");
        }
```

How can i achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can iterate over the rows of the values and try and find the specific data you're looking for in the first column of each row.

```
string searchData = "data";
for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)       
{
    if (values[0].Equals(searchData))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Found!");
    }
}
```

If you want to iterate the values column by column, you can use a nested for loop with the first one specifying the column index and the second one specifying the row index.